# Outlook 2007 assign multiple tasks at once

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, tasks, transfer

Is it possible to assign all marked tasks at once to a certain user?

Because if I have 200 tasks I don't want to assign each task separately. After clicking right mouse button "assign tasks" does not appear for all in the list only if one line is marked.

Comment: Is it your one-time only problem or you need to do that periodically?

Comment: It has to be done periodically or better constantly.